# angular 8 - component not loading in the html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I was wondering if anyone had a similar issue like what Im having now?

I was following the angular course on Scrimba, its lecture 7, angular component.

I created the angular app using cli command and tried to load and change the "loading..."
section with "hello world" like the lecture, 
even copied the whole code and paste it in my local files and refresh the index.html but still didnt work!

I wonder if anyone knows or had a similar problem?
Mucho thanks for any help!

this is what my app.component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>`,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  constructor(){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = 'hello';
  }
}
```

and this is what my app.module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomersComponent } from './customers/customers.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is my index.html

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularProject</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
      Loading...
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't know what changes you made (we have no idea of what this lecture is), and we don't know what "doesn't work" means. Tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Post the relevant code.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. You forgot to finish your sentence apparently.

Comment: @JBNizet I was trying to learn how the angular component works and how to use the ngOnInit function, and what I expected to happen was that in the "app-root", the default text is "Loading..." but I wanted to add the "hello" text when the ngOnInit function is triggered. But currently, it does not add the "hello" in the browser/html. Hope this is clear now? Could you maybe help me?

Comment: The default text is not Loading. Loading is what appears between the moment when the page is loaded by the browser and the moment when the JavaScript code has been parsed and executed by the browser. At this time, Angular instantiates the component and replaces the default, static text "Loading" by the dynamic template of the component. As you were told already, you can't have both template and templateUrl. Which one do you want to keep? if it's templateUrl, what the the app.component.html file contain? What do you expect to see, and what do you see instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can't have these 2 at the same time

```
  template: `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>`,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
```

You can remove one of those

By the way your project is setup I must say you are missing some config file. You should follow these step to get your app running

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app
ng serve
```

Note this is the error I have so you need to follow above step

[image]

Comment: here is the stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyrcq3
what is crazy is that on stackblitz, it works but when I test with my local browser, it only shows the <p> part and not the "helloComponent". When I check the inspect element, the hello component is added in the "elements" but it has 0x0 width and height. When I hardcode it, such as background-color, it does show that color but not the hello component data. It drives me crazy help :((((

Comment: this is the repository - https://github.com/jjyoon7/angular-newbie 
Thank you so much for looking into it!

Comment: Seem like you dont have tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json. Just update my answer.

Comment: hello! you were right, I did not follow those steps before so now I have tried that. But when I test locally, still has the same issue where in the inspect element it does not have any width and height property. Also now it throws error in the stackblitz as well, where it says it cannot find "index.html" and "main.ts" under src folder, where it does exist. :(((

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue (i.e blank page). I followed the simple steps given for demo Angular app given in  https://angular.io/guide/setup-local  (also similar steps are given in other sites for demo app), however it was not showing anything. I tried to view the source and could not spot any issue. After long try, i thought it could be issue with my Firefox browser (I was having ubuntu 16.04, Firefox v51). So, I upgrade Firefox latest version v71 and it displayed text from App module (As expected). 
Please try to check your web browser, it might be similar issue. 
Good luck

Comment: thnks bro its browser issue bcz i was using IE but when i used chrome , my problem resolved

Answer (score -2):

I had similar issue (i.e blank page). I upgraded my browser and it worked.

Comment: The answer should be in detail. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer